# Ошибка деплоя артефакта tomcat idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, tomcat

Такая проблема что после написания первого контроллера spring mvc томкат перестал деплоить war artifact, переустанавливал artifact не помогло, вот весь output - http://pastebin.com/WibNL8qP , заранее спасибо. Прилагаю скрины tomcat конфиг [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще такая заморочка, может из за нее [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подключена библиотека servlet-api?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

оно?